# How to Monitor existing Process in .NET

Tags: .net, process

I cooked up a simple slave process that I can start and monitor using the .NET `System.Diagnostics.Process`. However, what if I want to discover an existing process. I can do so easily enough by name. However, I also want to monitor the *Standard Output*. This is simple enough when my code basically owns the process. I can even set the `RedirectStandardOutput` flag in the monitoring `Process` instance. But when I call `BeginOutputReadLine`, or try to access `StandardOutput` in any way, I get an exception, i.e. `Additional information: StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet`. Which leads me to believe there's more going on when I create a process from .NET providing the start info. So... My question is basically that. Is there a way to attach to an existing process and monitor its standard output stream?